# How to show error bar with standard deviation in a barplot using Seaborn in Python

Tags: seaborn

I have noticed that sns.barplot uses standard error for error bar as default [1](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn-dev/generated/seaborn.barplot.html?highlight=bar#seaborn.barplot). Is there a way to change it to SD?

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, ci=???)
```

Answer (score 8):

*Edit 2017:*

Now, there is an option in `Seaborn v0.8` to show standard deviation in several plot types. In the particular case of the question:

`ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, ci="sd")`

---

The answer is: it is not possible to do it directly.

---

I had asked the [same question in the GitHub issue tracker for this library](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/926):

> Could it be possible to represent standard deviation bars instead
>   standard error bars in barplots?
>
> I don't know if it is already possible tweaking ci and estimator. If
>   this feature is not too complex to implement in Seaborn, I could help
>   to develop it as much as I can.

The developer of this library (mwaskom) answered:

> No, it's not possible, sorry.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12395735)

Comment: @Aleksej / Morales This clearly is an answer, and it looks like the correct and authorative answer. I've edited the answer a bit to make it clearer how it came to be.